# Copying stuff from InDesign to Flash via Illustrator programmatically

Tags: flash, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I noticed that a complex layout from InDesign stays nicely in place when you first copy it to Illustrator and from there to Flash, instead of exporting for Flash in InDesign.

Is there any way to use ExtendScript or similar to automate this process? The workflow would be something like

1. Select & copy elements in InDesign
2. Open new Illustrator document
3. Paste elements there, select and copy them again
4. Open new Flash document, paste there
5. Repeat X 10000

Or should I use a general computer automation tool, like Do It Again to create the process?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine all the applications can be scripted via ExtendScript Toolkit/BridgeTalk, but I don't know if the copy/paste will be straight forward. You could try using AppleScript on osx to move from app to the other and copy/paste.

If you want something that would run all operating systems, I suggest having a look at [Project Sikuli](http://sikuli.org/) from [MIT HCI CSAIL](http://www.csail.mit.edu/videoarchive/researchdemos/hci). It's fairly straight forward to use and works pretty well if properly configured. Check out some of the [demos](http://sikuli.org/demo.shtml).